# htaccess redirect for query url including a path

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have to redirect url

http://www.nv-pedia.de/pedia/?q=node/630

to

http://www.nv-pedia.de/hafenplan-s256-arsdale/

My solutions doesn´t do anything and unfortunately i have not found an answer on this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)630(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule $/hafenplan-s256-arsdale/?  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your regular expressions in both the RewriteCond and RewriteRule are wrong, and your RewriteRule has a syntax error.  You should read the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/), including the [introduction to regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)q=node/630(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^pedia/?$ /hafenplan-s256-arsdale/? [R=301,L,NC]
```